# Is using setState in every iteration of a loop bad practice?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

Here is a little code snippet:

```
async componentDidMount() {
    ...
    this.state.postList.forEach(element => {
      this.fetchItem(element);
    });
}

async fetchItem(query) {
    ...
    this.setState( previousState => {
        const list = [...previousState.data, data];
        return { data: list };
    });
}
```

I'm curious to know if using `setState` in every iteration of a `forEach` loop is a bad idea or not. I'm suspecting that it impacts performance, but I'd like to know for sure because this seemed like the simplest solution to this problem.

Comment: your `fetchItem()` function is `async` but the calls to it do not include `await`

Comment: I don't think it's that bad because it's async. You'd want to think of a better idea if you were doing synchronous stuff.

Comment: @Pointy that's the value of async! You don't have to wait! Looks to me like he wants to make the requests concurrently.

Comment: Well sure, but the effects are significantly different. Assuming all the calls return in more or less the same amount of time, by not waiting the code is setting up a situation in which a flurry of responses all call `setState` over a short period of time; I think that's kind-of the heart of the question.

Comment: If you're doing asynch stuff then the simplest would probably be `Promise.all(array.map(asyncFunction)).then(result=>this.setState...`

Comment: calls to `setState` are batched, so in the worse case scenario where all requests return rapidly at or near the same time, i think all of your  calls would be batched into one big update. I also agree with @HMR about using `Promise.all` and then doing your setState with the end result, but i don't think it will matter much for a small list

Comment: @r3wt `setState` is not batched when using promise or  async/await

Comment: @mohamedRamrani um ... no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm curious to know if using setState in every iteration of a forEach loop is a bad idea or not.

If it would be directly inside of an iteration then definetly *yes*, as React than has to merge all the updates you make during the iteration, which will probably take much more time than if you would just set the state after the loop.
In your case however, you do start an asynchronous action in each iteration, and as all asynchronous tasks finish at different times, the updates aren't run all at once. The main benefit of your approach is that if these asynchronous tasks take some time (e.g. if you fetch a lot of data for each), then some information can already be shown, while some are still loading. If all those asynchronous calls only load a small amount of data, well then you should actually change your API to deliver all the data at once. So it really depends on your usecase wether thats good or bad.

Answer (score 5):

Here's an alternative approach: Update your `fetchItem` to just return the item. In your `componentDidMount` use `Promise.all` to get all the items and then commit them to the state in a single operation.

```
async componentDidMount() {
    const items = await Promise.all(this.state.postList.map(element => fetchItem(element)));
    this.setState({data: items});
}

async fetchItem(query) {
    const item = await getItem(query) // however you accomplish this
    return item;
}
```